# Relative Positioned Child in Absolute Positioned Child

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm currently trying to fully understand how all the positioning code works and to make everything responsive in my website. I've come across a rather irritating issue.

THE ISSUE
-I have a div that is positioned relative (id: news_content) and is within a div that is positioned absolute (id: page).  When I try to move news_content using positioning commands top and left, left is the only one that is reacting.  While the top command isn't moving news_content at all.

```css
/*Global*/
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
table {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/*Global Divs*/
#page {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#nav_main {
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:14%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:0;
}



/*Navigation*/
#nav_content {
    background-color:gray;
    width:12.5%;
    height:86%;
    position:fixed;
    top:14%;
    z-index:-1;
    }
    #nav_side_container {
        background-color:black;
        width:60%;
        height:93%;
        position:relative;
        top:3.5%;
        left:18.75%;
        }
    #nav_side {
        background-color:red;
        width:75%;
        height:93%;
        position:relative;
        top:3.5%;
        left:12.75%;
        }
        #nav_side table {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            font-family:'Playball';
            font-size:1.25em;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            }
            #nav_side table td {
                width:100%;
                height:33.33%;
                border-top:0.1em solid black;
                }

/*News*/
#news_content {
    background-color:red;
    width:87.5%;
    height:86%;
    position:relative;
    top:14%;
    left:12.5%;
    z-index:-2;
    }
/*
#news {
    background-color:black;
    width:10em;
    height:10em;
    position:relative;
    left:10em;
}
#news_main {
    background-color:blue;
    width:10em;
    height:10em;
    position:relative;
}
#news_side {
    background-color:green;
    width:10em;
    height:10em;
    position:relative;
}

/*Articles*/
#articles_content {
    background-color:blue;
    width:87.5%;
    height:86%;
    position:relative;
    left:12.5%;
    z-index:-2;
    }

/*Future Plans*/
#future_content {
    background-color:green;
    width:87.5%;
    height:86%;
    position:relative;
    left:12.5%;
    z-index:-2;
    }
```

```html
<div id="page">
     <div id="nav_main">
        </div>
        
        <div id="nav_content">
            <div id="nav_side_container">
                <div id="nav_side">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>News</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Articles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Future<br>Plans</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="news_content">
            <div id="news">
            </div>
            <div id="news_main">
            </div>
            <div id="news_side">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="articles_content">
        </div>
        
        <div id="future_content">
        </div>
    </div>
```

..

-No idea what the problem is to be truthfully...  It could be my knowledge on how relative and absolute positioning is wrong or my code being complete haywire.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `#page` id doesn't have a height on it.  If you give it `height: 100%;`, that should do it.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work for me.  Why do you think it was not having height defined on the id to be the problem?  Just curious :p

Comment: Okay, that is odd.  I honestly have no clue why it's working in a fiddle.  I just tried again adding height to it and still nothing.